# Why "Safe Finder" pops up in Safari, how to block, get rid of it?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions, virus, adblock

Is it a virus or why in my Mac? How can I get rid of it?

I want to use google search engine, not this..

[image]

Comment: Your browser is indeed infected. Check extensions, remove website data in privacy tab of Safari Preferences, Check latest installations either by `system_profiler SPInstallHistoryDataType` in Terminal or, system report in About This Mac. Also, search this site for similar questions. Don't use personal use websites for some time.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205288/yahoo-is-taking-over-my-google-search-from-my-safari-on-my-mac https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171941/yahoo-search-has-hijacked-all-my-internet-browsers-safari-firefox-how-to-rem  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90894/where-has-the-searchme-extension-for-safari-and-chrome-come-from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362860/safari-hijacked-by-safe-finder-change-homepage-preference-greyed-out?rq=1